# My code is not loading images

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having an issue where my code acknowledges the correct objects to pull in. However, when I test my file the images are not being pulled in at all. I've double checked and I'm getting a 404 response, but the files exist in the correct directory.

```
//JSON OBJECT SAMPLE IS BELOW, A SEPARATE FILE....
var reviews = [{
        Id: "ajjhwejkssl",
        Title: "The little camera that could!",
        Rating: 5,
        Body: "TEXT HERE",
        CreateDate: new Date(2012, 5, 23, 14, 12, 10, 0),
        Owner: {
            Id: "kwergiueerwq",
            Name: "Bugs Bunny",
            Url: "./users.html?id=kwergiueerwq",
            AvatarImage: "./avatars/bugsbunny.jpg",
            IsFeaturedReviewer: false,
            CreateDate: new Date(2012, 2, 12, 9, 44, 0, 0)
        }
    }
]


//CODE
var data = reviews;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //console.log("browser: " + browser);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        try {
            //CREATE NEW REVIEW DIV
            var reviewPost = "<div class='review'><div class='clear'></div><div class='content'><div class='datePosted'>" + data[i].CreateDate + "</div><div class='avatar'><div class='header'><div class='rating'><img src='images/star-sprite.png'/><img src='images/star-sprite.png'/><img src='images/star-sprite.png'/><img src='images/star-sprite.png'/><img src='images/star-sprite.png'/></div></div><div class='clear'></div><div class='title'>" + data[i].Title + "</div><div class='memberImg'><img id='thumb' src=" + data[i].Owner.AvatarImage + "/></div><div id='member'><div class='reviewedBy'>Reviewed by <a href='' class='member'>" + data[i].Owner.Name + "</a></div><div class='membership'>Member Since " + data[i].Owner.CreateDate + "</div></div></div></div><div class='clear'></div><div class='message'>" + data[i].Body + "</div></div><div class='clear'></div>";
            if (data[i].Rating != null) {
                console.log("Rating: " + data[i].Rating);
            }
            //adds reviewPost inside of reviews
            review.append(reviewPost);
            //document.write(reviewPost);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error: " + e);
        };
    }
});
```

Any ideas and suggestions would be great.

Comment: Are you sure the location matches? Run something like fiddler or network tools within your browser and see what the exact URL is being requested.

Answer (score 0):

The dot in the paths doesn't matter, as I've learned, but:

Also, make sure that the avatars directory is in fact in the root of your web directory.

Comment: the `.` is completely irrelavent.   `.` means `this directory`

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I just hadn't ever seen or used that syntax before.